# Nothing happens when I try to run program to calculate mean, variance, and std dev

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

I am trying to produce the mean, variance and standard deviation of a user input array, but I am trying to keep everything in the subroutine other than gathering the data.

```fortran
Program dyn_array
implicit none
character (1) response
    integer :: N,data
    call stats(N)

Print *, "Enter the size of array:"
        read(*,*) N


Print *, "Enter the values of the array:"
   read*, data

contains
subroutine stats(N)
    implicit none
    integer, dimension(:),allocatable :: v
    integer, intent(inout)::N
    real :: arraysize,sumsquare,datas,mean,variance,std,a,tot
    integer :: i,j,k,x
    allocate(v(data),stat= x)
    if (x/=0) stop
     jloop: do j = 1,N
           read*,v(data)
        end do jloop
    tot=sum(v)
    sumsquare=0.0
    arraysize = size(v)
N_loop: do
    K_loop:do
            datas=v(data) * v(data)
            sumsquare=sumsquare+datas   
    end do K_loop
    mean=sum(v)/arraysize
    variance=(sumsquare-tot*tot/arraysize)/arraysize
    std=sqrt(variance)
    Print*, "Mean                   =",mean
    Print*, "Variance               =",variance
    Print*, "Standard deviation     =",std
    Print*, "Do you want to repeat for another array?"
    read*, response
        If (response =="y" .or. response == "Y") then
        deallocate(v)
    end if
end do N_loop

End subroutine

End Program dyn_array
```

Comment: You `call stats(N)` before you read in the values `N` and `data` to use in that call. There are other issues inside the subroutine relating to `v` and so on, but you'll never get the right answer calling in that order.